# Pyramid of Stars

Tags: c

Your job is to use for loops in order to print out pyramids of stars. Your program should take an integer as and argument, and print out an asterisk pyramid with a base of the provided size. For example, if the user input were 3, your program should print out:

```
*
**
***
```

Here's what I've done. The program doesn't have any errors but it do not print out the pyramid and returns as expected. Once I get it working I will add more if statements to account for bigger pyramids.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int size){
if (size == 0)
{return;
};
if (size == 1)
{printf("*\n");
};
if (size == 2)
{printf("**\n");
};
if (size == 3)
{printf("***\n");
};
if (size = 4)
{printf("****\n");
};
if (size == 5)
{printf("*****\n");
};
if (size ==6)
{printf("******\n");
};

 main(size-1);}
```

Comment: "I will add more if statements to account for bigger pyramids" -- no, you're supposed to use [`for` loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) to do this, obviously.

Comment: `Your job is to use`...

Comment: Please send some time with your instructor or TA to clarify your assignment. Anyone here could write what needs to be done for you, but it seems your missing too much of the fundamentals for that to be fair to you or your contemporaries.

Comment: I think I am close to finishing this assignment. There are no errors finally, and it print pyramids, but upside down. I just need help with this last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in no-way pretty, but it should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int size = 3,i;      //you can't just pass a value into main like that so I've initialised size here
    while (size){        //loop controlling line output
        i = 0;
        while (i++<size){//loop controlling * output within line
            putchar('*');//output a *
        }
        putchar('\n');   //output a newline (go to next line)
        size--;
    }
}
```

If you check the syntax of `for` loops, you should be able to translate this to use them pretty easily (I'm nice but I'm still not going to give you your entire assignment on a plate).

Comment: @CoolGuy haha yes, typo.

Comment: In this situation, as stated in the original problem, `for` loops are the optimal choice: The outer loop should look something like `for (i=1; i<=size; i++)` and the inner loop should look something like `for (j=1; j<=i; j++)`

Comment: @RPGillespie yup. but I'm not going to do the OP's entire assignment for him.  This is enough to give him an idea of what to do - I'll mention this in the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

become upside down is because the position of the main call is made to last.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc){
        int i;
        (void)main(argc-1, argv);
        for(i=0;i<argc;++i)
            putchar('*');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing row-column "graphics" is a two-dimensional problem, so you will need a 2D solution: TWO loops, one nested inside the other. You could get away with one loop - to print stars (asterisks) across a row, and re-invoke the program as you tried - except that the result will get smaller each time. To get larger, you would need two program arguments: max size and current row. You can't get away from the need for two pieces of data in this case.

Please try using two loops as someone else suggested in a comment.

I would call the desired result a "triangle", because to me a "pyramid" has to be symmetric left-to-right, so can only have rows of odd size.

Comment: Wow: as BLUEPIXY said, could recursively invoke main() *before* printing a row, so that would cause it to get larger each row, as intended. I guess I never thought of using the OS to do a job that a for loop could do... But the argument to main() has not been dealt with by anyone. It must be a character string.